# python dictionary and if statements

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, if-statement

I am trying to make a program that calculates grade point averages the user enters in a grade and then I compare the input to a dictionary. Here is my code I am sure what is wrong.

```
def average(g1):
    dic = {"a": [4.],"A": [4.],"A-": [3.66],"a-": [3.66],"B+":[3.33], "b+": [3.33],"B": [3.],"b": [3.],"B-": [2.66], "b": [2.66],"C+": [2.33],"c+": [2.33],"C": [2.],"c": [2.], "D+": [1.66],"d+": [1.66],"D": [1.33],"d": [1.33],"D-": [1.], "d-": [1.],"F": [.66]}

    for key in dic.keys():
        if g1 in dic.keys:
            print ("hello")
g1 = raw_input("Please enter grade 1: ")
average(g1)
```

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong? What happens when you run it? How does it differ from what you expected?

Comment: `for key in dic.keys():` what do you think this does? `dic.keys` what do you think this does?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the GPA value associated with the letter grade entered by the user:

```
def average(g1):
dic = {"A": [4.], "A-": [3.66], "B+":[3.33], "B": [3.], "B-": [2.66], "C+": [2.33], "C": [2.], "D+": [1.66], "D": [1.33], "D-": [1.], "F": [.66]}

for key in dic.keys():
    if g1 == key:
        print("GPA for '{g1}' = {value}".format(g1=g1, value=dic[key][0]))
        print ("hello")
g1 = raw_input("Please enter grade 1: ")
average(g1.upper())
```

sample output:

```
Please enter grade 1: a-
GPA for 'A-' = 3.66
hello
```

I simplified your dictionary by using only uppercase letter grades to which you can pass the user's input converted to uppercase with `str.upper()`.

Answer (score 0):

dic.keys() returns a list of all the keys in the dictionary. You don't need to loop through all the keys with a for loop. This should do what you want.

```
def average(g1):
    dic = {"a": [4.],"A": [4.],"A-": [3.66],"a-": [3.66],"B+":[3.33], "b+": [3.33],"B": [3.],"b": [3.],"B-": [2.66], "b": [2.66],"C+": [2.33],"c+": [2.33],"C": [2.],"c": [2.], "D+": [1.66],"d+": [1.66],"D": [1.33],"d": [1.33],"D-": [1.], "d-": [1.],"F": [.66]}

    if g1 in dic.keys():
        print('hello')

g1 = input("Please enter grade 1: ")
average(g1)
```

Comment: Just to be picky (since this question is tagged with Python 3): `dict.keys` doesn't return a list in Python 3, but an iterator of type `dict_keys`.